# Objective C - How to add a method to an existing class?

Tags: objective-c, function

How can i add a new method to NSString class.
I need to create a method that get's called on a string and returns an NSDictionary.
**I know that i can simply create a function that gets a string and return an nsdictionary, but i want to know how to add it to an existing class.**

```
NSString *myStr = @"some json string";
NSDictionary *dictionary = [myStr getJSONData];
```

Comment: http://theocacao.com/document.page/327 Categories are definitely better for organization, but you can literally add methods to classes at runtime. This tutorial is based off of the Objective C Reference

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use Objective-C categories. For example to add on to `NSString` define the following in a new .h/.m file:

```
@interface NSString (CategoryName)

-(NSString *) aNewMethod;

@end
```